# Has-one or belongs-to-many?

Tags: database, theory

It appears I just have some brain freeze and I don't get my head around the following.

I am writing a caravan renting/booking system. I have a table with a number of caravans. I also have a table with bookings. So I got it that between caravan and booking is a 1: n relation ship.

So now I need to introduce events (as in which shows are on display for a certain time) and pricing for the caravans on the events.
And this is where I cannot get my head around. I have a number of unique, non-overlapping events - about 40 each year. Each caravan is priced based on the event.

If I look at pricing<->event only, do I have a 1:1 relation ship? Hm, not really, because when I bring in the caravan, I could have multiple prices per event on *different* caravans.

Same applies for pricing<->caravan, just the other way round, if I am not mistaken.

What I gathered is that Caravan<->Event form an M: N relationship. This is the real-world representation in that sense that this combination is bookable. To represent this M: N relationship you need to introduce another linking table to break it down to two 1: N and N:1 relation ships. What I learned from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108742/three-sided-many-to-many-relationship-design is that Price in my case is a property of the relationship Caravan: Event.

I suspect that calling this linking table "Price" is misleading, but technically this represents the item what can be paid for and Price is only an attribute.

This is also the idea later, that this combination of Caravan: Event provides the daterange (from the Event) and then a Booking record can be created pointing to the Caravan.

No more puzzles.

Comment: You're puzzled because you're not clear on the real-world relationships of your data.  Make those clear and the database relationships will become clear.

Comment: Each Event has one pricing and one pricing belongs to one Event. Same for Caravan<->Pricing. But looking at Pricing<->Event again, which is a 1:1 relationship, does this make it then to a 1:n relationship when I look at it from a Caravan perspective? My answer would be yes, as there are then multiple prices per Caravan per Event. Or in other words, there are multiple Prices for each Caravan  Event, as there are multiple prices per Caravan (but different event).

Comment: It sounds like Price is an entity as well.  Unless it's merely a business rule.

Comment: Yes, Price is an entity.

Comment: You probably need a linking table between Pricing and Caravan.

Comment: In working with School systems, I have found a four-table architecture ::   Students  1/n  SectionLink   n/1  MasterSchedule  n/1  CourseCatalog